# Powershell script running over ssh to windows via teamcity

Tags: windows, powershell, openssh, teamcity-8.0

I am getting the following error in my TeamCity pipeline log

> An error has occurred which PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session
>   might have ended. + CategoryInfo : OpenError: (172.31.26.4:String) [],
>   PSRemotingDataStructureException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   PSSessionStateBroken

I'm running TeamCity 2018.2.4 (build 61678) which is running on windows 2012 R2 along with a single Agent on the same server. Powershell 6 and OpenSSH installed on both TeamCity and the Windows Server.

I can run the script locally from the Teamcity server via powershell and runs fine with no errors.